# How to disable two nodes to connect on the same port?

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-tcp

I'm making a multichat application and here is the [code](https://github.com/MARIEM96/Multichat). In this application I made a server and here is the code :

```
defmodule Multichat.Server do
  require Logger

  def accept(port) do
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(port, [:binary, packet: :line, active: true, reuseaddr: true])
    Logger.info "Accepting connections on port #{port}"
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp loop_acceptor(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    {:ok, pid} = DynamicSupervisor.start_child(Multichat.Server.ConnectionSupervisor, {Multichat.ClientConnection, client})
    :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process(client, pid)
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end
end
```

you can see in the code there is a client part :

```
defmodule Multichat.ClientConnection do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(socket), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, socket)
  def init(init_arg) do
    {:ok, init_arg}
  end

  def handle_call({:send, message}, _from, socket) do
    :gen_tcp.send(socket, message)
    {:reply, :ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_info({:tcp, _socket, message}, socket) do
    for {_, pid, _, _} <- DynamicSupervisor.which_children(Multichat.Server.ConnectionSupervisor) do
      if pid != self() do
        GenServer.call(pid, {:send, message})
      end
    end

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

I want when I start a node on a port, the other node can't but connect on another one. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In linux, listening sockets are bound to any of the device's IP or all of them (1), usually the default being listening in all of them (the `0.0.0.0` ip).
Once a process is listening in one `ip:port`, no other socket is able to listen in the same `ip:port` (2)

(1) This is not entirely true, because you have network namespaces and the IP_FREEBIND option.
(2) Again, not entirely true, you have the SO_REUSEPORT socket option.

So, in this case you have several options:

1. Set different ports for each node to be started locally, for example, using environment variables
2. Listen in different IPs for each node during development, for example, `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.2`
3. Set the SO_REUSEPORT option in the listening sockets
4. Use docker or other container/namespace technology to be able to start different nodes in different network namespaces.

Socket options are explained [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)
In Erlang, it seems that the relatively new [low-level socket API](https://erlang.org/doc/man/socket.html) has the `reuseport` option available, whereas, from the [inet documentation (gen_tcp)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2), it seems that `SO_REUSEPORT` is only available as a `raw` option.